# Static Fragments vs. Dynamic Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

What are the pros and cons of using a Static Fragment defined in XML as opposed to a Dynamic one in Java? Here are categories:  1. Maintainability, 2. Compatibility, and 3. Performance, 4. UX

Comment: As far as maintainability, it really depends on how you like to handle things; just like some people prefer adding views to layouts via xml while others prefer java (and vice versa). It is worth noting you can use java to work with views added in xml, but not the other way around (AFAIK). For compatibility you should have similar compatibility, that is Google's goal at least. Performance seems to lean towards xml as Google has, presumably, implemented more efficient ways of inflating views than we likely could. For UX, similar to 2, Google's goal is to minimize differences between the two.

Comment: And that is a comment because I am not 100% sure on it and for a `good` answer it would need a lot more info :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a big difference in using fragments through XML or dynamically through java code, depending on which you chose the main difference will be on how the user experiences the flow of the app.

**TLDR**: the below characteristics are shared both by fragments instatiated through XML and dynamically with java code (through `FragmentManager` API), but the Java code allows you to change, add, remove each fragment in runtime, allowing for a **flexibility** that would be impossible otherwise.

[image]

But to answer your question:

1 - Maintainability - about the same, you use the android:name attribute to define the `fragment` class you want to use VS using:

```
// get fragment manager
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

// add fragment
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
// alternatively add it with a tag
// trx.add(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment(), "detail");
ft.commit();
```

In the case of only one transaction, there is barely any effort either way.

2 - Compatibility: **about the same**, both are frequently used by developers everywhere

3 - Performance, the one time inflation process could be a little faster but they are **essentially even**.

4 - UX: here depending on your needs, there could be *no difference* or a ***huge one***.

So what's this big difference between XML or "dynamic fragments"?

Fragments instantiated through direct XML inflation **cannot** be dynamically managed on runtime through FragmentManager.

As an example, this means that once you inflate the fragment/layout you cannot send it to backstack and quickly bring another one upfront. Dynamic management of fragments can be used to give that fast single-flow experience inside one multipurpose activity to the user that is impossible  to get if you are jumping from one activity to the next.

After the initial FragmentTransaction above, you have the absolute freedom to reuse the same layout container for other fragments very quickly

```
// replace
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placehodler, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();

// remove
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_placehodler);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(fragment);
ft.commit();
```

"So why do we have XML instantiated fragments? We should ban them right now!"

Not so fast, if for example your purpose is simply to have a multi-pane window/layout in your app that **won't change too much** during its lifetime (ie. if you can stick with that layout until dismissing the activity) xml inflation would have no drawbacks and depending on the amount of fragments  you could be spared a lot of boilerplate FragmentTransactions code.

Another **important** use case could be to simply be prepared for the use of a different device `Configuration` such as **screen size**, or different **screen orientation** (like when using the app both on **tablets and phones** portrait/landscape), XML is a simple solution for providing a different layout for each of these (and other) device configurations.
[image: same app, different device configuration]

Sources:
[link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial)

[link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

[link](http://coreylatislaw.com/managing-static-and-dynamic-fragments/)

[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: @Clint Deygoo have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as the correct one, let me know if this helped =)